# Как взаимодействовать с объектами, когда они все находятся в одном объекте

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, объекты

Я взаимодействую с сайтом и получаю объект в котором находится много объектов с помощью:

```
JSON.parse(data.split("woo")[1]);
```

Я понял, что это объект через:

```
typeof(a1)
```

Если я сохраняю его в txt файл, то получается:

> [object Object],[object Object] и т.д.

Могу посмотреть количество объектов через:

```
a1.length
```

Терминал на вызов

```
console.log(a1);
```

выдает объекты через запятую с их свойствами. 
Но я не понимаю, что дальше делать. 
Как получить какой нибудь определенный объект из этой пачки? 
Как сохранить его потом ?
И так далее.

Comment: _Если я сохраняю его в txt файл_ = как именно сохраняешь?

Comment: fs.writeFileSync("a05.txt" , a1)

Comment: используй `JSON.stringify`: `fs.writeFileSync("a05.txt" , JSON.stringify(a1))` так как в противном случае твой массив будет приведен к строке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, что это не объект, а [массив](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Оператор [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) для массивов возвращает `'object'`, поэтому чтобы проверить является ли нечто массивом можно использовать [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

Таким образом у нас есть массив объектов. Число элементов в массиве записано в свойстве [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length). Элементы массива [индексируются](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) от `0` до `length-1`. Получить `i`-ый элемент можно обратившись через квадратные скобки:

```
array[i]
```

Можно перебрать все допустимые индексы и сделать что-нибудь с соответствующим элементом массива:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Или, используя [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
for (let element of array) {
    console.log(element);
}
```

Comment: `for (let element : array) {` -> _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :_

Comment: Спасибо большое, так и есть